# How to make a moving transition of points from a to b

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatterplot and I have two different sets of datapoints I am visualizing from the dataset. I want to animate the path from "red" to "blue" dots and show them like the blue point is moving from the red and getting its position. Is that possible with d3, and if so how can I do this?

The scatterplot I have currently with the plotted points is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wu65g40p/1/).

this is how I draw both sets of datapoints in the scatterplot:

```
    // blue dots
    svg.append('g')
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); } )
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); } )
        .attr("r", 4.1)
        .transition()
        .style("fill", "blue")



    // red dots
    svg.append('g')
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x1); } )
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y1); } )
        .attr("r", 4.1)
        .style("fill", "red")
}
```

Thank you for any kind of help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
Using the property transition and combining with duration in milliseconds. Look below:

https://jsfiddle.net/mathyaku/L5bpaxwv/1/

```
function drawScatterplot(data, selector) {
  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3.select(selector)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  //Read the data
  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));


  // Add red dots
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x1); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y1); })
    .attr("r", 4.1)
    .style("fill", "red")

  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
    .style("fill", "blue")


}

drawScatterplot(data, '#Scatterplot');
```

Comment: thank you so much! This looks good, but I don't want the red points to dissapear after they have been transitioned.

Comment: That's not difficult to do also.
You can start the blue points as transparent color on the red points position and then just apply the transition.

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/mathyaku/L5bpaxwv/11/

Comment: thank you very much for your help! This is what I wanted to achieve.